# how to add time picker along with date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have searched a lot in internet and tried them but all of them are not working my problem is how to display time picker along with date picker

i already have this code for date picker

```html
<html>
<head>

<title>datetimepicker</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jqueryui.css"rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <input class="w3-input   w3-border "  type="text" id="txt_fupdate" size="25" title="Follow Up Date" placeholder="Follow Up Date " runat="server" required>    
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $("#txt_fupdate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }).val()
                });

             </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

my question is how can i add or update that code to get time picker please help regarding this.

Comment: `jquery ui` doesn't have time picker by default but here is an addon `http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/`

Comment: or https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

Comment: check this:- http://jquer.in/jquery-plugins-for-html5-forms/datetimepicker/

Comment: @Mairaj i already tried them but im not able to get time picker

Comment: [Jquery date-time-picker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/) . It's working fine at my local end. Just download it and run the index.html file and check. Now use code accordingly to your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, you need a plugin,
Try this one: https://plugins.jquery.com/simple-dtpicker/

Remember to include required files in your folder

jquery.simple-dtpicker.js and jquery.simple-dtpicker.css

And your code suppose to look like this:

```
<html>

<head>
        <title>datetimepicker</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mugifly/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/72933bbe/jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mugifly/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/72933bbe/jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <input id="txt_fupdate" class="w3-input   w3-border " placeholder="Follow Up Date " required="" size="25" title="Follow Up Date" type="text" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#txt_fupdate').appendDtpicker({
                    "closeOnSelected": true

                });


            });
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Its simple and has several good features such localization.

Comment: its working fine but how to enter date in the format of *dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm*

Comment: i got that bro '  "dateFormat": "DD-MM-YYYY H:mmTT"' by using this we can change

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plugin: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Alternatively, I would suggest that you can add an extra textbox on to the right of the *datepicker* and bind it with time picker like [this](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) one.